# Entity with inheritance on relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I would like in Symfony 4 with doctrine use inheritance through a trait to add a new column to 2 different tables.

This is the structure of those 2 tables I want:

- `ManagerChildA` has a relation OneToMany with ChildClass
- `ManagerChildB` has a relation OneToMany with ChildClass
- `ChildClass` is a basic entity

This is what I tried:
Class `ManagerChildA` and `ManagerChildB` are same excepted the name

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ManagerChildARepository")
 */
class ManagerChildA
{
    use TraitManagerChild;

    ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ManagerChildBRepository")
 */
class ManagerChildB
{
    use TraitManagerChild;

    ...
}
```

This is my trait with the relation :

```
trait TraitManagerChild
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ChildClass", mappedBy="managerChildA|managerChildB", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $child;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->child = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...
}
```

This is the Child entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ChildClassRepository")
 */
class ChildClass
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ManagerChildA|App\Entity\ManagerChildB", inversedBy="child")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $managerChild;
    ...
}
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

**Edit:**

The issue is I can't generate the migration because I don't know how with one code add a relation in 2 entities. The issue is in the comment : `targetEntity` in the trait

This is what I want with a OneToMany relation (managers can have many children), but through a trait:
[image]

I don't speak really good English sorry :/

Comment: I think I understand the problem, but it's not explained  very clearly. Can you edit your question to explain what's the problem with what you tried?

Comment: the problem is, that the annotation would have to be different in both `ManagerChildA` and `...B`, you **can't** just go `mappedBy="managerChildA|managerChildB"` and expect it to work. because that annotation is in both entities then. How would doctrine know how to assign those properly? I would override the field in both entities so that each can have the proper annotation, and leave the trait either completely without the field or a field without the annotations ... probably ...

Comment: Why build a bidirectional relationship? just skip the `mappedBy` property and in your   Trait class make sure that the property points to ChildClass (as it already does). Then you can query for all ManagerChildB and ManagerChildA separately.

By the way, implementing a constructor in a trait is sure to land you in hell some way down the road ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: Change the child entity to have a relation for each manager:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ChildClassRepository")
 */
class ChildClass
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ManagerChildA", inversedBy="child")
     */
    private $managerChildA;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ManagerChildB", inversedBy="child")
     */
    private $managerChildB;
    ...
}
```

Then depending on your requirements you need to write a check or constraint to ensure the child has at least one managerChild set (and maybe not both?).

Solution 2: If your managerChildA and managerChildB classes are really similar you could also use  [table inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), use the trait in the mapped superclass and change the child entity to point to the mapped superclass like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ManagerChildSuperclass", inversedBy="child")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $managerChild;
```